# “Foxen” versus “oxes”

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

What is the difference between *fox* and *box* versus *ox*, that the first two are pluralized as *foxes* and *boxes*, whereas the last one is pluralized *oxen*?

**Note:** I know how to pluralize them. What I want to know is what makes them different from each other, *why* they are pluralized as they are.

*Joking: the plural of [box](http://foldoc.org/boxen) is [boxen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkrMsPiqG6M). [Kudos to [Mark](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/179031/foxen-versus-oxes/179039#comment373461_179031) for that first link]*

Comment: Related reading: http://lingwe.blogspot.com/2009/02/oxen-and-foxes-curious-life-and-death.html

Comment: The _-en_ was already being used on _fox_ in _vixen_, as a feminine suffix, with umlaut (o->i) and initial voicing (f->v).

Comment: Or rather: u > y > i. The "o" in "fox" is secondary.

Comment: Note that "[boxen](http://foldoc.org/boxen)" *is* a plural of "box".

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/180564/74434

Comment: @Mark As long as we don't start using _cockswain_ as the plural of _cox_. That would just be silly. ;-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The word *ox* comes from the Old English *oxa*.  In Old English, as in Indo-European languages in general (historically and even today), the number of a noun (singular or plural) and its function in a sentence—whether it was the subject, direct object, indirect object, or had some other relation to a verb or another noun—was largely (not solely) governed by sets of endings tacked onto it, or changes made to the vowels in it. These sets of endings or changes were called *[declensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_declension#Nouns)*, and each type of relationship associated with an ending is called a *case*.

There were [a number of declensions](http://www.wmich.edu/medieval/resources/IOE/inflnoun.html) in Old English; the two most prominent were the *weak declension*, containing the weak nouns, and the *strong declension*, containing the strong nouns. Old English *oxa* was a weak noun. The forms that we have of its descendant today are derived from the *nominative* case endings; these are the forms that would indicate that a noun is the subject of a sentence, or the forms that would be used when writing a list of nouns.

Since *oxa* was a weak noun, its plural form (the nominative plural form) was *[oxan](http://hord.ca/projects/eow/grammar/noun.php?id=4376&output=macron)*. Over the course of centuries, the *a* "weakened" to an *e*, giving us *oxen*.

*Fox*, on the other hand, comes from the Old English *fox*, which was a strong noun; its Old English plural was *[foxas](http://hord.ca/projects/eow/grammar/noun.php?id=592&output=macron)*, whence we get *foxes*.

The source I used to confirm the declension of *fox* has an entry for the Old English *box*; however, it has no declension information. Using [this translator](http://oldenglishtranslatorvps.co.uk/cgi-bin/oldenglishtranslator/perl/old_english_translator.pl), however, it appears that the nominative plural was *boxas*, giving us *boxes*.

Although Modern English has largely dropped the declensional suffixes we got from Old English, we occasionally see them peeking through, as we do here.

Comment: One might also consider our other two remaining vestiges: *child > children* and  *brother > brethren* (although the latter is now restricted to spiritual, ecclesiastical, or professional relationships).  **Note also** how the stressed vowel changes upon inflection in those two words, but does not do so in *ox > oxen*.  I would like to know more about that disparity myself.

Comment: I found some interesting statements in etymologies of "child"; I'll ask the question if you haven't already.

Comment: I’ve looked no further than the OED etymology entries.

Comment: Thank you very much, for your answer and for your clarification thereof!

Comment: Is there anything that decides whether a noun is "weak" or "strong"? ....if not, then all we did was just push the question back a few hundred years+ (if Old English [ended circa 1150](http://www.google.com/search?q=define+old+english&oq=define+old+english&aqs=chrome..69i57.6068j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8&gws_rd=ssl))....

Comment: I'm not sure I'd agree with that. If we kept pushing back, and pushing back, what we'd wind up with are questions like "Why did these two words ... and ... look different in language X (Old English, West Germanic, Proto-Germanic, Proto-Indo-European)?" The answers to those questions will vary greatly depending on the language; they're often fundamentally different questions - and may not be answerable.

Comment: Fair point....by the way, I only saw your response to my comment now, when I came back to look at the question for fun....in the future, if you want to make sure someone sees a comment, write the `@` symbol somewhere in the comment, like this: @MattGutting

Comment: Please attribute correctly (showing the source in the hotlink, say). For two reasons. Firstly, I believe it's necessary to avoid copyright infringement rules. Secondly, we have no idea what 'this translator' is as the link no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it has to do with word origin. [The proto-Germanic word for oxen was ukhson](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=ox&searchmode=none) so the ending didn't move too much. Meanwhile "fox" comes from "fukhs" which followed words like "box" to the es ending.

Comment: Actually, _*uhson_ (or _*uhsō_, more likely) was the PG for _ox_, not _oxen_. The PG plural was probably _*uhsniz_. Both had been somewhat refashioned by the time of Old English.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have two systems in a language. Traces of an old system, and a newer system that is more regular and easier. *Oxen* is a plural form of the old system. In German, where you have a relatively irregular plural formation with several endings and vowel change as an extra difficulty, we have still the plural form *Ochsen*, singular *der Ochs*.
Compared to German, the English plural system with the ending *-s/-es* is easy apart from a handful of plural forms that stem from the old system and which in most school books are labeled as exceptions.

Although the English plural system is easy, English has developed a new difficulty, nouns that have no plural form because they are uncountable or nouns with identical *sg* and *pl* form and a lot of other numerus particularities.