# How did "oxen" (plural of "ox") survive as the only plural form with the Old English plural ending -en?

Tags: grammatical-number, suffixes, historical-change, old-english, irregular-plurals

*Oxen* is a rare exception in English where it is the only common English word that retains the original Old English plural ending -en. (Note: *Children* and *brethren* are formed a bit differently, please see the note at the end.)

*[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/oxen#etymonline_v_44893)* has this explanation for *oxen*:

> plural of ox, it is the only true continuous survival in Modern English of the Old English weak plural (see -en (1)). OED reports *oxes* occurs 14c.-16c., "but has not survived."

The usage of the plural form *oxes* can be seen as far as the year 1905 per the latest citation in *OED* with a plural form of *ox*.

> **1905**
> Hitch my oxes To de plow. 
> <sub>A. V. Culbertson, *Banjo Talks* 41</sub>
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*, s.v. “ox, n., sense 1.a”, July 2023. https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/9070656295</sub>

*OED* lists the plural forms below for different periods:

| Period | Plural form |
| --- | --- |
| Old English | oexen (*Mercian*), oxan |
| Old English–Middle English | exen, exin |
| Old English– | oxen (*rare*) |
| Middle English | exon, ocsen, oksen, open (transmission error), oxene, oxis, oxnen, oxon, oxone, oxsen, oxsyn, oxun, oxys |
| Middle English–1500s | oxin, oxyn, oxyne |
| Middle English– | oxes (now *regional*) |
| 1500s | oxeson |
| 1800s– | oxens (*U.S. regional*) |

<sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*, s.v. “ox, n., Forms”, July 2023. https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/2903238464></sub>

Note that, *oxen* is mentioned as rare in Old English even, and the plural form *oxes* survived till modern English period per the citations in *OED*. There aren't any citations with *oxen* after the latest citation with a plural form of *ox* (as *oxes*) from 1905 in *OED*. [*Vocabulary.com*](https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/wc/why-do-we-say-oxen-and-not-oxes/) has this brief history about -s and -en plural forms:

> You may have heard that English is a Germanic language. The *-en* ending on plurals is something we get from our German roots. In Old English, some nouns were made plural with *-s* and *-es* as they are today, but many nouns took *-en* to become plural.
>
> The s-form plurals became dominant in northern England first, while the en-form hung on in southern England. By the 14th century the s-form became dominant everywhere, but people didn't let go of the en-form completely; as late as the 16th century the plural of eye was *eyen* and the plural of hose was *hosen*. Today only a few en-forms survive; the most common are *oxen* and *children*.

The above explanation doesn't exactly answer the question though. What happened in history that *oxen* has become the accepted plural form? Did the southern usage gain traction in time; and if yes, how? Could there be an influential work or writer (from 1900s or earlier) that revived or popularized the usage *oxen*?

---

Note: *Children* and *Brethren* are other similar exceptions but they don't have the pure plural form with *-en* and their formation is a bit different than *oxen*. *OED* has this note for the plural word *children*:

> In early Middle English, the r-plurals (see Forms 2aγ) are affected by the spread of the (originally weak) plural -en in southern English (see -en suffix<sup>3</sup>), yielding the double plural children (see Forms 2aδ), which becomes the usual form in southern dialects of Middle English and in modern standard English (compare likewise the development of *brethren*, plural of brother *n.*).
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*, s.v. “child, n., Etymology”, July 2023. https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/2625064881</sub>

---

The question linked below is related and it has a good answer, but I'm asking something different: 
[Etymology of certain words ending in "-en"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180564/etymology-of-certain-words-ending-in-en)

Comment: It's maybe pointless arguing about such niceties, but [brethren](https://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-plu1.htm) is a regular plural of brether with the en ending, in contrast to children which is a double plural. You might argue that brethren is no longer used as a plural and oxen is still the only plural in en. (And other dialect forms such as [sistren](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sistren) also exist.)

Comment: Also man, pl. men, needs explanation.

Comment: Well, there are towns and surnames with *oxen* in them. *Oxendine* is very common here. It's pronounced *Oxen-dean* by GPS (like in England, I gather), but it's *Oxen-dine* here or pronounced very distinctively by native tribes.

Comment: *It also helps that, in Old English, ox was spelled oxa, and it simply sounded better to keep on the n from the previous Proto-Germanic word ukhson (ultimately from Proto-Indo-Europan uksen, meaning "any male animal" in general)* https://www.etymologynerd.com/blog/oxes-and-oxen

Comment: @StuartF By "brethren is no longer used as a plural", do you mean that it is no longer used at all, or that it is used but in some other way than as a plural?

Comment: @Tetsujin When my daughter was little, her plural for **finger** was **fingern**.

Comment: It was never broadly used, but in some circles the plural of VAX (computer made by DEC) was Vaxen.

Comment: @user888379 Yeah, I remembered that too, not because I was there (I'm from '89), but from the Jargon File. And Unixen, and "boxen" for hardware... :)

Comment: Lederhose, Lederhosen?  Hausfrau, hausfrauen? Gestalt, gestalten?

Comment: @user888379: Emacsen

Comment: @user66974 "Male animal" somewhat ironic, that.

Comment: @user888379 RE: "never broadly used" I have never heard any other plural form than VAXen? VAXes sounds just as wrong to me as oxes or sheeps. Do you know any different?

Comment: @Lorraine I think the intended meaning was that the word VAX itself (whether singular or plural) was never used at all by most of the Anglosphere, not that only a small section of those who do use it pluralise it as VAXen.

Comment: @Xanne If you mean that the Proto-Germanic noun _*mann-_ needs explanation, you’re right: no fully satisfactory explanation for its unusual forms in PG, nor for the discrepancy between the nominative singular in individual Germanic languages. But there’s no doubt that the vowel in _men_ is the result of _i_-umlaut of _a_ to _e_ before the original _*-i_ from the old plural form (West-Germanic _*manni_).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Old English **oxan**, plural of **oxa**, was very common, appearing in the psalter, the bible, and laws, among other places, although the spelling **oxen** is attested in only one place, in a document relating to Bury St Edmund's possessions, rents, and grants.

The genitive plural form of **oxa**, often with a syncopated vowel,  was **ox(e)na**. That genitive form is attested in place names (cf. **oxenaford**, Middle English *Oxenford*, ModE *Oxford*, **oxeneham** ModE *Oxnam*, **oxenesetene** ModE *Oxsettle Bottom*, **oxnaleage** ModE *Oxleigh* and *Oxley* , a woodland clearing or a natural glade, meadow, lea, a plant name **oxna-lib**  glossing Latin *oleotropius* ModE *oxlip, ox-heal*), as a unit of measure of land (**oxnagang**, ModE *ox-gang*, one-eighth of a "hide"), and in genitive   (**oxna-paeþ** ModE *oxens' path*)  and partitive genitive constructions (**ic bohte fif getymu oxena**, **ic bohte an getyme oxena**, ModE *I bought five teams of oxen*, *I bought one team of oxen*) and those uses appear not only in texts dealing with quotidien farming and mercantile situations but notably in passages from the Bible, which would frequently have been heard by audiences from all social and economic classes.

The plural appears as **oxen** and is very well-attested in Middle English in a wide range of texts. It appears in various spellings, including *oksen, exen, oxon, oxen, oxsen, oxsin, ocsen* (see the MED). Its appearance in proverbial contexts (**Moche uolk of religion zetteþ þe zuolȝ be-uore the oksen**. *Many people of religion set the plow before the oxen*)  and laws is very strong evidence that it was widely used.

P.S. I have a copy of the Old English corpus and found these attestations by searching it. (I studied Old English and Middle English as an undergraduate and graduate student, back before the days of personal computers, but they haven't changed much in the interim.)

P.P.S. I stumbled upon a book, *Working Oxen* by Martin Watts. 1999.  "... a survey of their use in Britain, their impact upon the countryside, and the relics that can still be found: yokes, bows, shoes, housing and place-names. Martin Watts is curator of the Ryedale Folk Museum in North Yorkshire." [Google Books description] and "Oxen were one of the most important sources of motive power in the British countryside... The working ox has left a lasting mark on the language, landscape and culture... Historians rarely mention or study them. It is as if a history of twentieth century were to ignore the impact of the tractor and the lorry. The purpose of this book is to redress that balance." [from the blurb on Amazon].

Answer (score 16):

I don't know of any satisfying reason for it.

Note that when the OED says "Old English– oxen (rare)", it means that the specific spelling O-X-E-N was rare in Old English. It doesn't say that *oxan* was rare, and from the point of view of later development, the difference between Old English *oxan* and *oxen* is irrelevant: it was normal for Old English "a" in unstressed syllables to be weakened to schwa, which in Middle English came to be spelled "e". Compare the development of the Old English infinitive ending *-an* to *-e* in the case of words like *drīfan* > *drive.*

There is a general principle that irregular forms persist longer in frequently used words, but I'm not sure how much it can do to explain the use of the form *oxen.* I don't think we talk about *oxen* as much as we used to.

It seems conceivable that the fact that the singular already ends in an /s/ sound made it a bit harder for the sibilant plural to become established, but I'm not really sure if that played an important role: obviously there are multiple other words ending in *-x* that do form their plurals in *-xes,* such as *foxes, boxes, axes.*

Comment: The printing press slows down language change, so we spoke of them enough in the 1600s and 1700s that it became frozen.

Comment: Could this potentially be something preserved by biblical texts? This concordance lists 95 instances: https://thekingsbible.com/Concordance/oxen

Comment: @RyanDonovan Maybe, although lots of other language features in KJB have gone away.

Answer (score 5):

There has been a certain geek revival of this construction in [regexen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/regexen) and [VAXen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/VAXen).
It started as hard ironic but has become mainstreamish for regexen. Um, as mainstream as anything involving regex can be.
(The DEC VAX line is 20 years obsolete so VAXen is mainly a feature of old-timer stories to emphasize that they're old-timer stories. A server room becomes a "herd of VAXen.")

Comment: Never answer a question with a story about regex; now they'll have *two* problems.

Comment: Haven't heard any of these yet but have heard a room of unix server "boxes" called boxen...